# layout_centerHorizontal item is not centered when another view is at the right side of it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

When I use `layout_centerHorizontal` to center an item in the view horizontally and another item is in the right side of it, it's not centered.

[image]

But when I delete the second item, It moves to the center.

[image]

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#13D372"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/message"
        android:background="#125632"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [android:gravity="center_horizontal"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#attr_android:gravity) will place the childs (your two TextViews) in the horizontal center of its container.

Remove `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` from parent and keep `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in your child layout (`TextView`) to only center this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"    <!--here-->
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#13D372"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/message"
            android:background="#125632"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```